# GNU screen use complex command as shell

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to use a command with multiple arguments as my `shell` from the perspective of GNU Screen. For some context, I want to make sure that my `.bash_profile` gets sourced, but I don't want to change into my home directory. If at all possible, I'd like to push the complexity of handling this into my `.screenrc` rather than spreading it around. Is this possible?

Can I use multiple arguments or a script as my shell in GNU Screen?

The `shell` directive is sorta complex and accepts a variety of things. It seems to accept simple commands

```
shell /bin/bash
```

and environment variables

```
shell $SHELL
```

and leading dashes for interactive shells (which can be combined with environment variables)

```
shell -$SHELL
```

However, it does not appear to accept multiple space-delimited arguments using the obvious syntax (i.e. `shell /bin/bash --init-file ...`)

I've been using the following workaround:

a script called `shellhere`

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://serverfault.com/a/586272
exec bash --init-file "$HOME"'/.bash_profile'
```

an environment variable `$SHELLHERE` set to the absolute path of `shellhere` inside my `.bash_profile` ... and

```
shell $SHELLHERE
```

inside my `.screenrc`.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: That's bizarre. Why would you load `~/.bash_profile` *inside* a screen window? That file is meant to be loaded when you log in. Just run `bash`, it'll load `~/.bashrc`, which is meant to be loaded for every interactive shell.

Comment: @Gilles, When I had a non-trivial `.bashrc`, I ran into issues when editing the commit message in `git` and `hg`. That led me to believe that `.bashrc`s "should be" fairly pristine... I see now that that's inaccurate.